# Why blocks don't collide with ball

Tags: python, pygame

I want ball to collide with blocks but ball don't.
plane is name about bar which player can move (70,10)
block(brick)is brick that player must break(80,40)
game size is (480*640)
here is create block

if block is less than 30 block create by randomly
in random space

```
    while len(wblock) <= 30:
        down = random.randint(0, 9)
        right = random.randint(0, 6)
        wb = random.randint(1,42)
        wblock.append([right*80, down*40, wb])
```

when down and right is point block size is 80*40

```
    if wball[0] >= 460:
        bx = bx*(-1)
    if wball[0] == 0:
        bx = bx*(-1)
    if wball[1] >= 640:
        running = False
    if wball[1] == 0:
        by = by*(-1)
    wball[0] += bx*2
    wball[1] += by*2
    screen.blit(ball, (wball[0],wball[1]))
    ballrect = pygame.Rect(ball.get_rect())
    ballrect.left = wball[0]
    ballrect.right = wball[1]
```

here is ball and bar collide
also , boll go through of bar... why

```
    position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    planepos = (position[0], 600)
    position[0]
    screen.blit(plane, planepos)
    planerect = pygame.Rect(plane.get_rect())
    planerect.left = planepos[0]
    planerect.top = planepos[1]
    if planerect.colliderect(ballrect):
       by = by*(-1)
       print(by)
```

now this code is collide of ball and block

```
    index = 0
    for brick in wblock:
        index += 1
        brickrect = pygame.Rect(blocks[brick[2]].get_rect())
        brickrect.left=brick[0]
        brickrect.top=brick[1]
        if brickrect.colliderect(ballrect):
            wblock.pop(index)
            by = by*(-1)
            index -= 1
        screen.blit(blocks[brick[2]], (brick[0],brick[1]))



    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.flip()

screen.blit(gameover, (10,100))
pygame.display.flip()

while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit(0)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

is my code. could get my question?

when ball move he move through blocks and stuck in sky

Comment: Is the size of the screen (480*640) or did you mean (640,480).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mjaor issue is when you set up the `ballrect`. You have to set `ballrect.top` rather than `ballrect.right`:

```py
ballrect = pygame.Rect(ball.get_rect())
ballrect.left = wball[0]
ballrect.top = wball[1] # <---- `top` instead of `right`
```

Note, you can set the position of the rectangle by an keyword argument, when you retrieve the rectangle from the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) (see [`pygame.Surface.get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect)):

```py
ballrect = ball.get_rect(topleft = wball)
```

Furthermore the rectangular area which is covered by the Surface is returned by [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit):

```py
ballrect = screen.blit(ball, wball)
```

---

If you want to evaluate, if the ball is in bounds, then you have to evaluate if the right of the ball does not exceed the right of the screen, the left does not exceed the left, the top does not exceed the top and the bottom does not exceed the bottom.
Create [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object for the ball and compare the `left`, `right`, `top` an `bottom` of the rectangle to bounds. Invert `bx` respectively `by` if the ball is out of bounds:

```py
screerect = screen.get_rect()
ballrect = ball.get_rect(topleft = wball)

if ballrect.left <= 0 or ballrect.right >= screerect.right:
    bx = -bx
if ballrect.top <= 0 or ballrect.bottom >= screerect.bottom:
    by = -by

wball[0] += bx*2
wball[1] += by*2

ballrect = screen.blit(ball, wball)
```